# Encontrar producto con mayor precio de lista de un arreglo de Objetos

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

tengo un arreglo de objetos de tipo productos y estoy tratando de obtener por consola el producto cuyo precio de lista sea el mayor. El codigo que uso para obtener lo que busco es el sgte:

```js
class producto{
  constructor(id,nombre,marca,modelo,precio,categoria){
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.categoria = categoria;
  }
}

const product1 = new producto(1,'telefono','samsung','A10',3200,'tecnologia');
const product2 = new producto(2,'telefono','LG','K22',2100,'tecnologia');
const product3 = new producto(3,'telefono','XIOMI','REDMI9',1200,'tecnologia');
const product4 = new producto(4,'telefono','MOTOROLA','GPALY',4200,'tecnologia');
const product5 = new producto(5,'telefono','SONY','ERICKSON',6200,'tecnologia');

const productoslist = [product1,product2,product3,product4,product5];
const productMayor = productoslist.filter(x=>Math.max(x.precio));
console.log(productMayor);
```

Cuando ejecuto el codigo, no me sale la respuesta que estoy buscando (el producto con mayor precio de lista).Lo que me bota por consola es el arreglo de los 5 objetos. No se si estoy de forma correcta el Math.max. Agradeceria que pudieran indicarme que cambios deberia hacer para obtener lo que busco

Comment: `Math.max()` devuelve el número más grande de todos los que le pases. Si solo le pasas uno siempre será ese el más grande. Por otro lado, filter lo que hace es devolver una lista de acuerdo al booleano que devuelva la función lambda. Puede serte más útil ordenar el arreglo con `.sort()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar un Sort y tomar el valor del primer elemento de la siguiente forma.

O podes usar Reduce.

```js
class producto{
  constructor(id,nombre,marca,modelo,precio,categoria){
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.categoria = categoria;
  }
}

const product1 = new producto(1,'telefono','samsung','A10',3200,'tecnologia');
const product2 = new producto(2,'telefono','LG','K22',2100,'tecnologia');
const product3 = new producto(3,'telefono','XIOMI','REDMI9',1200,'tecnologia');
const product4 = new producto(4,'telefono','MOTOROLA','GPALY',4200,'tecnologia');
const product5 = new producto(5,'telefono','SONY','ERICKSON',6200,'tecnologia');

const productoslist = [product1,product2,product3,product4,product5];
const productMayor = productoslist.sort((b, a) => a.precio - b.precio)[0];
const productMenor = productoslist.sort((a, b) => a.precio - b.precio)[0];

console.log("Mayor Valor",productMayor);
console.log("Menor Valor",productMenor);
console.log("Lista ordenada",productoslist.sort((b, a) => a.precio - b.precio));

//Aca con Reduce.
const mayor = productoslist.reduce((mayor, item) => mayor = mayor?.precio > item.precio ? mayor : item ,{});
console.log("Mayor reduce",mayor);     
   
const menor = productoslist.reduce((menor, item) => menor = menor?.precio < item.precio ? menor : item ,{});
console.log("Menor reduce",menor);
```

Comment: Tengo una duda en "const productMayor = productoslist.sort((b, a) => a.precio - b.precio)[0];" el [0] que significa?

Comment: El Sort devuelve el mismo array pero ordenado, con el [0] estas tomando el primer elemento de ese array, es el índice. ahora te agrego el console log del array completo.